# npm install --save isn't running - EPEERINVALID error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run `npm install --save` but for some reason I'm getting this weird error:

```
135 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save"
136 error node v4.7.2
137 error npm  v2.15.11
138 error code EPEERINVALID
139 error peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
139 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.3.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
139 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.3.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
139 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.3.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
139 error peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.4 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
140 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm using linux and a few days ago I've executed an `apt-get update` that maybe screwed my global node configurations.

Can someone assist ?

Comment: have you tried updating npm?
try this sudo npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: do you mean running npm update --save ?

Comment: yes you have to update npm package. i have updated my old comment please run that

Comment: @AsifSaeed what you've offered seemed to work...! but now I'm getting those:
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: i think your other modules are outdated now. You can update them and yes these are just warnings

Comment: That's ok you can ignore that warning. It will not cause any problem.